# Test handling of return value of a function

Tags: c++, bash, parsing, code-analysis

I am currently trying to improve the quality of a C++ project (under Linux) with multiple developers. Nearly all the functions of our project do return a certain ErrorCode. I want to enforce the treatment (avoid forgetting) of the error codes returned from the functions and thus I am looking for a open source tool/ bash script, that parses my code and identifies if a function is used without an assignment and issues a warning if so.
For exanmple

```
setMyVar(uint32_t bla); // Naughty
```

instead of

```
ErrorCode currentError = setMyVar(uint32_t bla); // Potentially naughty but I am ok with that
```

A must would also be that the procedure works for the usage of namespaces ,such as

```
ErrorCode currentError = PM::initialize();
```

and ideally things like

```
if( PM::initialize() == PM::Init_Error)
```

would be considered correct usage as well. Any suggestions how to tackle this kind of problem without having to implement a sophisticated code-parser?

EDIT: I also want to avoid modifications in my source code or respectively I want to have a read-only script that identifies the issues.

Comment: You want to verify that *your* code notices error signals, is that right?

Comment: @ Beta I want to make sure that me and my developers treat our defined errorcodes that our functions return. Ideally I would want to run a script that outputs sth. like: "Error: return value of function bla() no treated"

Comment: Have you considered using exceptions rather than return values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GCC and Clang support warnings for unused return values.

```
static __attribute__((warn_unused_result)) int test() { /* code goes here */ }
```

Any call results now in a warning when the return value is not taken into account.

```
test(); // WARNING: Ignoring return value of function declared with warn_unused_result attribute
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I should have added, that i do want to avoid modifying the actual code especially not by any sort of automated script.

Comment: Without modifying your code you can give PVS Studio a try. Warning V530 looks very promising. http://www.viva64.com/en/d/0119/

Comment: PVS-Studio can only run under Windows and is thus not relevant. They propose to use cppcheck on Linux Platforms, however cppcheck can't even handle Namespaces

Comment: Okay, the proposed method really seems like the way to go. Thanks